# Create SQL query for the following tables

Tags: python, sql

A database is composed of 4 tables: Table1, table2, table3 and table4.
[image]

---

For a given query **Q**. `If Q = Name_1`. I want to select all the fields in tables *1*, *2*, *3* and *4* and save them in an array using python.

---

create Tables:

```
Create Table table1 (ID1 INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100));
Create table table2 (ID2 INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100),ID_T1 INT, Foreign Key(ID_T1) references table1(ID1));
Create table table3 (ID3 INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100),ID_T1 INT, Foreign Key(ID_T1) references table1(ID1));
Create table table4 (ID4 INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100),ID_T2 INT, Foreign Key(ID_T2) references table2(ID2));
```

---

Insert Data in tables:

```
insert into table1 (ID1,NAME) values ("1", "john");
insert into table2 (ID2,NAME,ID_T1) values ("1", "math","1");
insert into table3 (ID3,NAME,ID_T1) values ("1", "physics","1");
insert into table4 (ID4,NAME,ID_T2) values ("1", "friend of","1");
```

Comment: please clarify what you mean query Q=Name_1

Comment: School work? What have you tried so far? How did it go?

Comment: Q = a string any name i'll  give an example. My problem Is with table 4 I'll type the query

Comment: Actually I created this design. But i thinks now it's very hard to extract the data

Comment: Is there a website where i can test my queries?

Comment: @HaniGoc You can test queries at http://sqlfiddle.com/ (including providing scheme, test data and seeing the explanation for different sql engines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 
    JOIN table3 as t3 ON t1.ID_table1 = t3.ID_table1
    JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.ID_table1 = t2.ID_table1
    JOIN table4 as t4 ON t2.ID_table2 = t4.ID_table2
```

Comment: Wedo My question is why did you use Join?

Comment: Your table1 has foreign key in table3 and in order to get relation data from that table you need to use JOIN 
http://www.sql-tutorial.net/sql-join.asp

Comment: Can I add Where statement before Join? WHERE t1.NAME ="John" For example?.

Comment: No, you should use it after all joins